# Grails custom validater, getting a reference to the field name

Tags: grails, global, shared, customvalidator

I am trying to write a generic custom validator for a property, to make it generic i need a reference to the field name within the closure, the code is as follows
In config.groovy

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
nameShared(validator: {val, obj, errors->
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,15}")
        Matcher m = p.matcher(val)
        boolean b = m.matches()
        if(!b)
        errors.rejectValue('name', "${obj.class}.name.invalid", "Name is invalid")

    })
```

in My domain class

```
class Student{
  String name

  static constraints = {
       name(shared:'nameShared')
   }
}

class Teacher{
  String firstName
  String lastName

  static constraints = {
     firstName(shared:'nameShared')
  }
}
```

I want to use the same validator for both name and firstName, but since i am hardcoding the fieldName in the validator, it will always work for name and not firstName, so i want to know if there is anyway i can get a reference to the fieldname and make the validator generic, please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the variable `propertyName` to get the name of the validated property.

From the grails [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html):

*The Closure also has access to the name of the field that the constraint applies to using `propertyName`*

```
myField validator: { val, obj -> return propertyName == "myField" }
```

Comment: Just tried searching for this in the grails docs and had to go back to grails 2.1 to find that snippet.  This might be the only useful place on the internet to easily find this gem.  https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.1.0/ref/Constraints/validator.html

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your validator-closure inside another function like this:

```
def getValidator(myValue) {
  return { val, obj, errors ->
    // make use of myValue
  }
}

myField validator: getValidator('foo')
```

Comment: yeah, that also makes sense, but i was looking for a default way to access field name, which aiolos mentioned, anyways thanks for your help.